# How and where does Python modify my PATH variable

Tags: bash, mac, shell, python, environment-variables

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` is in my `PATH` variable, and I didn't put it in. I don't want it in my Path. I have looked at these obscure files that might have added this in my PATH but I have no idea where I should look and I can't find **WHO EDITED MY PATH**. This is driving me insane, from my understanding the `PATH` is reconstructed after a reboot, which means that some program is running behind the scenes to sneakily add this to my `PATH`.

```
~/.bashrc
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d/
/Library/StartupItems
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

And Yes I have looked at "solutions" that want me to trim it from the `PATH`, but it isn't what I want, what I want is to find **WHO EDITED MY PATH** in the first place. I have uninstalled `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/` and it is still added in my path, is there any other solution than to burn my computer.

Comment: `~/.bash_profile`? `~/.profile`?

Comment: You won a cookie, here it is: . There was a `~/.profile` and a `~/.zprofile`, both culprits.

Answer (score 1):

Future me here, so as @DavidPostill pointed out, I didn't look in `~/.profile` and sure enough, it was there `~/.zprofile` for `zsh` so here where **YOU** should look for if you searched for this question:

## BASH

```
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d/
```

## ZSH

```
~/.zprofile
~/.zshrc
/etc/zprofile
/etc/zshrc
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d/
```